# How do I check the exit status of a Makefile shell invocation?

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which runs a program which on success return a non-zero value, and on failure return another non-zero value. I know that I can ignore the exit status by prefixing the command with -, but that does not work because I need to know if the command succeeded.

Comment: The first step is to submit a bug report to the maintainer of the program that returns non-zero on success.

Comment: Well, the program is from a commercial vendor, so I doubt that they will change the behavior of the program.

Comment: @trondd GNU make is developed by the GNU project, which isn't commercial. It's the opposite: it's free software.

Comment: The program executed from the Makefile is proprietary, not GNU Make.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can test the returned value on a second command on the same Makefile line, using the shell `$?` variable that contains the last returned value.

For example with the `false` command that would obviously stop the compilation:

```
test:
    /bin/false ; /usr/bin/test "$$?" -eq 1     # <-- make does not stop here
    /bin/echo "Continues ..."
    /bin/false                                 # <-- make stops here
```

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
command || [ $$? -eq v ]
```

as your command, substituting *command* with the command, and *v* with the value returned on success.

(This is just a more compact version of Didier Trosset's answer.)

Comment: This will not work as-is in a makefile, because the `$?` will be interpreted according to make variable definitions.  You need to use `$$?` instead.

Comment: Comparing to Didier Trosset answer, this one will also pass when command returns with status 0 (in my case that is not what I wanted) !

Comment: @Vitaly Polonetsky: I was assuming *tertium non datur*.  You can tweak it however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the tool behaves on fail, you could just check for the existence of the output file. something like:

```
@if test ! -f $(FILE); then exit 2; fi
```