# How do I check the exit status of a Makefile cmd.exe invocation?

Tags: windows, makefile

I want to check if GIT is installed in Windows during my build process and later do processing regarding to that. So, the idea was

```
check_git:
    git  > gitcheck

GIT_PRESENT = $(shell type gitcheck)

ifeq ($(findstring recognized, $(GIT_PRESENT)), recognized)  
#do nasty stuff
else
#do other stuff
endif
```

because cmd.exe says:

> ***Git*** is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

if Git is not installed, and I just wanted to check for the "recognized" keyword.

Of course it's not working because I realized that i must check for the exit status, which I read in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817298/how-do-i-check-the-exit-status-of-a-makefile-shell-invocation) thread.

I'm using cs-make 3.81, thats why I'm generating a file first. 
I realize that probably the "nice" way to do this doesn't exist... Also, I'm relatively new to this stuff and this is my first post so be gentle.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to control target rule behaviour based on this or actual make-level behaviour based on this?

Comment: I want to generate a few status flags which I integrate into my source code with e.g. if GIT is present then this flag gets in one of my struct's with: ' -D'GIT_FLAG=$(FLAG)' '

Comment: So then that is make level changes based on the presence of git? To set make variables for later use?

Comment: Yes, it seems so! Sorry, I have some problems understanding your semantics, as I'm relatively new to this and English is not my native language.

Comment: Try `GIT_PRESENT := $(shell git --help >nul 2>&1 & if %errorlevel% equ 0 ( echo GIT_PRESENT )` and see if that works for you. That should set `$(GIT_PRESENT)` to `GIT_PRESENT` when git exists and leave it blank otherwise. If git isn't in your `%PATH%` then you will need to put the path on that command line.

Comment: I see what you did there... OK, thanks for your help man. I currently don't get the expected behavior overall, but it probably isn't related with your code. I'll post the answer when I succeed. Thanks again, it really helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's what I did with the generous help from Etan:

```
GIT_PRESENT := $(findstring Git, $(subst \,$(space),$(shell echo %path%)))

ifeq ($(GIT_PRESENT),Git)  
    git_info = Git detected!
    ver_num = $(lastword $(shell git tag))
# and more nasty business...
else
    git_info = Git not detected! Values below set to default.
    ver_num  := 0.00.000
# and even more nasty business...
endif
```

Of course, Git has to be included in %path%, but anyway it is a prerequisite for Git to function from Windows cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

I believe `GIT_PRESENT := $(shell git --help >nul 2>&1 & if %errorlevel% equ 0 ( echo GIT_PRESENT )` will set the `GIT_PRESENT` variable to "GIT_PRESENT" when git is found (in the default %PATH%, use an explicit path in the call if it isn't in %PATH%).